# Django Rest Framework Serializer DateTimeField validates input data as AD and not take input with month 2(FEB) having more than 29 days

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, python-datetime

I am taking input date from the application, which they provide in BS which is Nepali Calendar system, this however created a problem for validation, as month number 2 ie. feb in AD has only 29 days whereas in BS it has 31 days

```
serializer.is_valid():
```

gives error that the date is not in correct format

What can i do to reevaluate my validation process

Comment: would you provide, models, view, serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So changing the serializer field from

```
measured_time = serializer.DateTimeField()
```

to

```
measured_time = serializer.CharField()
```

did the job for me.
but i had to manually change the validated charfield to datetime format before saving it, which i did by manually creating the data for the table with the provided instances